# Add Billing Address Validation in Stripe.js

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have a Django Saleor based website which is using stripe.js to manage the payments. During the checkout process, I am collecting the billing address as part of the checkout process but once I enter valid card details (even though billing address is incorrect) the payment is still successful. On the stripe dashboard I can see that the street and postcode check failed but the payment is successful. Anybody know how I can enable this.

My end goal is to make sure where the billing address doesn't match, these transactions are declined.

Comment: You want to enable a custom Radar rule for this in your Stripe account to block charges that fail the ZIP code or the Line 1 verification: https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#traditional-bank-checks

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: I got it working @koopajah. Just configured the radar rules under the dashboard, didn't realise the cost an extra 2p though! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you create an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block charges on cards with an invalid ZIP code or an invalid Line 1 address, the best solution is to use Radar rules. This is documented in: https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#traditional-bank-checks